# UITableView selecting row programmatically not having expected effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with (say) five rows in the only section. The code to edit a custom cell all works, but the problem occurs when I need to reload the table data with new data that has fewer rows, say two. The programme crashes if I have been editing a row that has a higher index than the maximum number of rows in the reloaded table. The exception shows that it is trying to access the higher numbered element beyond the limit of the new table number of rows.

I have tried putting:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

in just before the

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: need more explanation, if app crashes put error log.

Comment: If your editing cells action works it doesn't mean it is done correctly. I think you should paste here the code where you change your table view data, table view datasource and table view delegate methods

Comment: we need all tableView delegate methods, please write them down

Comment: What is the source of your TableView? Array? You need to refill the array and then reload.

Comment: I do refill the array - it gives the correct (new) answer in - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, deselecting the old row (i.e. whilst the old data source was still current) and then selecting the first row with the new data source fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can only mean that you are accessing the first row here:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

when you do not have the first row.

When you are reloading the tableview, make sure you have atleast one row.

Try doing this:

```
if([self.tableview numberOfRowsInSection:0]>0)
   [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Comment: I checked that I have the correct number of rows by putting debug in:- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Answer (score 0):

I believe you used the code below to unselect your cell

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

If so you should use this instead

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```